Querying custom metrics in NewRelic
I am using the Node.js agent for NewRelic.
I have been looking at sending custom metrics to NewRelic where the values are objects with keys, e.g.
import newrelic from 'newrelic';
...

const customMetricContent = {
    id: 1023,
    kind: 'content',
    mediaType: 'image',
    received: Date.now(),
    count: 1,
    total: 1,
    min: 1,
    max: 1,
    sumOfSquares: 1,
  };

newrelic.recordMetric(`Item/ReceivedRecord`, customMetricContent);

The last 5 keys are stated in the documentation to be required, so I have included them above.
My question is, can I query the custom metrics in NRQL by attribute value?  So, for example, if I wanted to select all metrics received on Monday 21st April with an kind of content and a mediaType of image?
I haven't been able to find an explicit example in the Node documentation for NewRelic.
